# How to check map network drive connection?

Tags: vb.net

I want to check whether the network drive had map before I map the network drive.
I use this code to map the drive.

```
 Dim network = New IWshNetwork_Class()

                network.MapNetworkDrive("Z:", ServerDc, Type.Missing, username, pwd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IWshNetwork_Class` appears to be a class in the Windows Script Host Object Model COM library.

```
Dim Network As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshNetwork_Class
Dim Drives As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshCollection_Class
Drives = Network.EnumNetworkDrives
For DriveCounter As Long = 0 To Drives.Count – 1 Step 2 
    MsgBox(Drives.Item(DriveCounter) & " is mapped to " & Drives.Item(DriveCounter + 1))
Next
```

Have a look at [this PDF](http://www.philippursglove.com/VB/binaries/UsingWSH.pdf) for more information...

Comment: Error occur at Count –1. The '-' is not valid.